# How to solve $Cov(g(X),Y)$ when $(X,Y)$ has bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

I have a problem I cannot solve.

> Suppose that $(X,Y)$ has the bivariate normal distribution. Prove that 
>   $$Cov(f(X),Y)=\frac{Cov(f(X),X)Cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}$$

Comment: What is $f$ and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I know nothing more but using definition and making addictional assumptions I managed to solve this.